White Screen after Booting Raspian but the OS is running, How can i fix that?
We've been working for years now with the raspberry pi and used it in a big project. Out of sudden we see on newer RaspiOS Versions this effect, that the raspi screen (Official 7" Screen) turns slowly white after the splash screen. we don't see this effect with older RaspiOS Versions.
So the Version that we see this effects are:
2024-03-15-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img
2024-03-13-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img
and with this image we don't get this problem:
2023-12-05-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img
Are there some changes in the display driver that could make a white screen?
We tried many things on the internet and nothing helped and we think really it is because of this newer RaspiOS version.
Here is a Video of the boot process:
https://youtu.be/GMKvtj8AhdM
and here is the boot log:
113877 kernel: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
114044 kernel: Linux version 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07)
114182 kernel: KASLR enabled
114293 kernel: random: crng init done
114386 kernel: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
114460 kernel: efi: UEFI not found.
114563 kernel: Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000000dc00000, size 512 MiB
114658 kernel: OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
114745 kernel: OF: reserved mem: 0x000000000dc00000..0x000000002dbfffff (524288 KiB) map reusable linux,cma
114889 kernel: OF: reserved mem: 0x000000003ef642c0..0x000000003ef646bf (1 KiB) nomap non-reusable nvram@1
114985 kernel: OF: reserved mem: 0x000000003ef64700..0x000000003ef647e1 (0 KiB) nomap non-reusable nvram@0
115077 kernel: Zone ranges:
115164 kernel:   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
115248 kernel:   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
115333 kernel:   Normal   empty
115407 kernel: Movable zone start for each node
115482 kernel: Early memory node ranges
115586 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
115662 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
115736 kernel: Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
115812 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA32: 19456 pages in unavailable ranges
115885 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA32: 16384 pages in unavailable ranges
115956 kernel: percpu: Embedded 30 pages/cpu s85672 r8192 d29016 u122880
116027 kernel: pcpu-alloc: s85672 r8192 d29016 u122880 alloc=30*4096
116101 kernel: pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
116172 kernel: Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
116250 kernel: CPU features: detected: Spectre-v2
116321 kernel: CPU features: detected: Spectre-v3a
116390 kernel: CPU features: detected: Spectre-v4
116484 kernel: CPU features: detected: Spectre-BHB
116561 kernel: CPU features: kernel page table isolation forced ON by KASLR
116649 kernel: CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
116722 kernel: CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 1742098
116792 kernel: CPU features: detected: ARM errata 1165522, 1319367, or 1530923
116878 kernel: alternatives: applying boot alternatives
116959 kernel: Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0  smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:26:19:7A vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=d8ecbb4f-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
117034 kernel: Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash", will be passed to user space.
117106 kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
117177 kernel: Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
117249 kernel: Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 996912
117345 kernel: mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:off, heap free:off
117417 kernel: software IO TLB: area num 4.
117487 kernel: software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000037400000-0x000000003b400000] (64MB)
117562 kernel: Memory: 3337176K/4050944K available (13376K kernel code, 2210K rwdata, 4260K rodata, 4864K init, 1083K bss, 189480K reserved, 524288K cma-reserved)
117635 kernel: SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
117705 kernel: ftrace: allocating 43116 entries in 169 pages
117776 kernel: ftrace: allocated 169 pages with 4 groups
117847 kernel: trace event string verifier disabled
117917 kernel: rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
117990 kernel: rcu:         RCU event tracing is enabled.
118078 kernel: rcu:         RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
118156 kernel:         Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
118265 kernel:         Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
118358 kernel:         Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
118436 kernel: rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
118508 kernel: rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
118586 kernel: NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
118657 kernel: Root IRQ handler: gic_handle_irq
118727 kernel: GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
118798 kernel: rcu: srcu_init: Setting srcu_struct sizes based on contention.
118932 kernel: arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
119012 kernel: clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
119086 kernel: sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
119161 kernel: Console: colour dummy device 80x25
119242 kernel: printk: console [tty1] enabled
119321 kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=216000)
119399 kernel: pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
119497 kernel: LSM: initializing lsm=capability,integrity
119583 kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
119663 kernel: Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
119740 kernel: cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
119822 kernel: RCU Tasks: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1 rcu_task_cb_adjust=1.
119899 kernel: RCU Tasks Rude: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1 rcu_task_cb_adjust=1.
119978 kernel: RCU Tasks Trace: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1 rcu_task_cb_adjust=1.
120054 kernel: rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
120134 kernel: rcu:         Max phase no-delay instances is 1000.
120208 kernel: EFI services will not be available.
120283 kernel: smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
120356 kernel: Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
120450 kernel: CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd083]
120527 kernel: Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
120640 kernel: CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd083]
120735 kernel: Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
120824 kernel: CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd083]
120900 kernel: smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
120979 kernel: SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
121078 kernel: CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
121152 kernel: CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL1 Support
121226 kernel: CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
121303 kernel: CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
121388 kernel: alternatives: applying system-wide alternatives
121484 kernel: devtmpfs: initialized
121565 kernel: Enabled cp15_barrier support
121642 kernel: Enabled setend support
121720 kernel: clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
121798 kernel: futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
121873 kernel: pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
121949 kernel: DMI not present or invalid.
122024 kernel: NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
122100 kernel: DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
122182 kernel: DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
122262 kernel: DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
122338 kernel: audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
122431 kernel: audit: type=2000 audit(0.036:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
122509 kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
122587 kernel: cpuidle: using governor menu
122661 kernel: hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
122737 kernel: ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
122814 kernel: Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
124033 kernel: platform fe101000.cprman: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /soc/dsi@7e700000
125114 kernel: bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
126442 kernel: platform fe101000.cprman: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /soc/dsi@7e700000
127838 kernel: platform fe700000.dsi: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /soc/cprman@7e101000
128983 kernel: raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2024-02-29T12:24:53, variant start
130078 kernel: raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is f4e2138c2adc8f3a92a3a65939e458f11d7298ba
130242 kernel: Modules: 2G module region forced by RANDOMIZE_MODULE_REGION_FULL
130328 kernel: Modules: 0 pages in range for non-PLT usage
130412 kernel: Modules: 517792 pages in range for PLT usage
131920 kernel: bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma-controller: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
132129 kernel: iommu: Default domain type: Translated
132215 kernel: iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: strict mode
132293 kernel: SCSI subsystem initialized
132373 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
132484 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
132566 kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver usb
132642 kernel: pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
132718 kernel: pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
132796 kernel: PTP clock support registered
132874 kernel: vgaarb: loaded
132949 kernel: clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
133023 kernel: VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
133099 kernel: VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
133199 kernel: FS-Cache: Loaded
133276 kernel: CacheFiles: Loaded
133351 kernel: NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
133426 kernel: IP idents hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
133504 kernel: tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 2048 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
133581 kernel: Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
133657 kernel: TCP established hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
133733 kernel: TCP bind hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
133808 kernel: TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
133883 kernel: MPTCP token hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 98304 bytes, linear)
133957 kernel: UDP hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
134055 kernel: UDP-Lite hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
134138 kernel: NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
134213 kernel: RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
134331 kernel: RPC: Registered udp transport module.
134413 kernel: RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
134487 kernel: RPC: Registered tcp-with-tls transport module.
134562 kernel: RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
134635 kernel: PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
134707 kernel: Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
134780 kernel: kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 44 bits
134911 kernel: kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
134990 kernel: kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
135090 kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 16724K
135170 kernel: Initialise system trusted keyrings
135248 kernel: workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=20 bucket_order=0
135323 kernel: zbud: loaded
135399 kernel: NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
135474 kernel: Key type id_resolver registered
135549 kernel: Key type id_legacy registered
135628 kernel: nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
135706 kernel: nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
135783 kernel: Key type asymmetric registered
135863 kernel: Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
135938 kernel: Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 247)
136034 kernel: io scheduler mq-deadline registered
136113 kernel: io scheduler kyber registered
136189 kernel: io scheduler bfq registered
136299 kernel: irq_brcmstb_l2: registered L2 intc (/soc/interrupt-controller@7ef00100, parent irq: 23)
137491 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
138565 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
139619 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
140598 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00bfffffff -> 0x0400000000
141527 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
142507 kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
143659 kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
144819 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
148361 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
151936 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
153073 kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie3v3 not found, using dummy regulator
154225 kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie3v3aux not found, using dummy regulator
155337 kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie12v not found, using dummy regulator
156239 kernel: brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
157194 kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
158041 kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
159140 kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3cold
160030 kernel: pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
160916 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
161812 kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
162715 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
163761 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
164709 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
165615 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 27
166542 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 27
166803 kernel: simple-framebuffer 3ea50000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0x3ea50000, 0x177000 bytes
167326 kernel: simple-framebuffer 3ea50000.framebuffer: format=a8r8g8b8, mode=800x480x32, linelength=3200
167419 kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
167539 kernel: simple-framebuffer 3ea50000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
168438 kernel: iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
168600 kernel: vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
168685 kernel: brd: module loaded
168764 kernel: loop: module loaded
168885 kernel: Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
169856 kernel: bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
170995 kernel: unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
171170 kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver r8152-cfgselector
171260 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
171343 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
171425 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
172553 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
173633 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
174672 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
175821 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0300240000000890
176790 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
177789 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
178690 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
180009 kernel: usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.06
181296 kernel: usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
182755 kernel: usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
184554 kernel: usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 xhci-hcd
185836 kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
187061 kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
188086 kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
189217 kernel: usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.06
190494 kernel: usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
192344 kernel: usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
193846 kernel: usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 xhci-hcd
195328 kernel: usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
196582 kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
197917 kernel: hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
198155 kernel: dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
198248 kernel: dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
198330 kernel: dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
198411 kernel: dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
198488 kernel: Module dwc_common_port init
198570 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
198648 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
198726 kernel: mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
198805 kernel: sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
198946 kernel: sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
199031 kernel: sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
199133 kernel: ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
199213 kernel: hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
199292 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
199367 kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
199443 kernel: hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available
199521 kernel: NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
199599 kernel: Key type dns_resolver registered
199677 kernel: registered taskstats version 1
199752 kernel: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
199831 kernel: Key type .fscrypt registered
199906 kernel: Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
200813 kernel: uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
203214 kernel: uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
203383 kernel: fe201000.serial: ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 36, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
204187 kernel: serial serial0: tty port ttyAMA1 registered
204983 kernel: bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
205758 kernel: bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
206571 kernel: mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
209305 kernel: mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
209500 kernel: of_cfs_init
209584 kernel: of_cfs_init: OK
209662 kernel: clk: Disabling unused clocks
209741 kernel: mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
209817 kernel: Freeing unused kernel memory: 4864K
209893 kernel: Run /init as init process
209972 kernel:   with arguments:
210049 kernel:     /init
210124 kernel:     splash
210199 kernel:   with environment:
210273 kernel:     HOME=/
210347 kernel:     TERM=linux
210420 kernel: mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
210514 kernel: mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDXC card at address aaaa
210590 kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SN64G 59.5 GiB
210664 kernel:  mmcblk0: p1 p2
210739 kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SN64G 59.5 GiB (quirks 0x00004000)
212078 kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
213319 kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
214542 kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
219955 kernel: usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
221009 kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
222021 kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
223530 kernel: usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
224466 kernel: i2c i2c-22: Added multiplexed i2c bus 0
225324 kernel: brcmstb-i2c fef04500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
226160 kernel: brcmstb-i2c fef09500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
227431 kernel: i2c i2c-22: Added multiplexed i2c bus 10
228653 kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c045, bcdDevice=27.20
229735 kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
230871 kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
232116 kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
232256 kernel: [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
232339 kernel: input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C045.0001/input/input0
233262 kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C045.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2/input0
233382 kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
234112 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
234233 kernel: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
234960 kernel: rc rc0: vc4-hdmi-0 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0
235101 kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-0 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input1
235181 kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-0 HDMI Jack as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/sound/card0/input2
235884 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fef00700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
235990 kernel: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
236639 kernel: rc rc1: vc4-hdmi-1 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1
236739 kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-1 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1/input3
236819 kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-1 HDMI Jack as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/sound/card1/input4
237507 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fef05700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
238198 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe700000.dsi (ops vc4_dsi_ops [vc4])
238918 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
239669 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
240362 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
241028 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe20a000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
241694 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe216000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
242365 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fec12000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
242464 kernel: [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for gpu on minor 1
242546 kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem fc7a1f9e-4967-4f41-a1f5-1b5927e6c5f9 ro with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
243389 kernel: vc4_dsi fe700000.dsi: transfer interrupt wait timeout
244115 kernel: vc4_dsi fe700000.dsi: instat: 0x00000000
244216 kernel: [drm:vc4_dsi_host_transfer [vc4]] *ERROR* DSI transfer failed, resetting: -110
244935 kernel: tc358762 fe700000.dsi.0: error initializing bridge (-110)
245037 kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
245702 kernel: vc4-drm gpu: [drm] fb0: vc4drmfb frame buffer device
245807 systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
245898 kernel: NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
245973 kernel: Segment Routing with IPv6
246048 kernel: In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
... systemmd startup ...
714959 kernel: vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
720014 kernel: bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
720368 kernel: [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
730899 kernel: snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
738986 kernel: mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
758900 kernel: bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
786911 kernel: [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
902934 kernel: rpi-gpiomem fe200000.gpiomem: window base 0xfe200000 size 0x00001000
975438 kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
993120 kernel: rpi-gpiomem fe200000.gpiomem: initialised 1 regions as /dev/gpiomem
171043 kernel: bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
354958 kernel: rpivid_hevc: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
446907 kernel: bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
454902 kernel: bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
455203 kernel: bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
506924 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
508399 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
526927 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
527331 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
527495 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
527662 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
527783 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
527919 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
596681 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
597484 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
597692 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
597814 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
608275 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
608701 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
608897 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video20
609053 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video21
619007 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video18
619346 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 image_fx
619531 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video22
619665 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video23
619778 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
619891 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
620000 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
620110 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
647044 kernel: alsactl[385]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
648139 kernel: alsactl[383]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
661255 kernel: bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
692379 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video31
692535 kernel: bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode_image
692674 kernel: rpivid feb10000.codec: Device registered as /dev/video19
692832 kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
726943 kernel: edt_ft5x06 10-0038: supply iovcc not found, using dummy regulator
... 



Why on earth would you use a new image rather than upgrading?

Our first version of the project was built in 2023 and the screen and everything works. And i flashed the sd card with the newest version that was published then. Now the second version of our project is coming, and i flashed the sd card with the newest image (like always, new pi new sd card installation via raspi imager) but then i had this weird effect…

All the versions you listed are raspios-bookworm-arm64. They are all the same version if you just did an upgrade (or dist-upgrade) they would have identical apps to a new image!

Yes, i know, but the question is still, why the screen gets white after booting with the newer build? Can you help me with this?

which part is so difficult to understand? Three different images are burnt to an SD card: 2024-03-15-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img 2024-03-13-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img
2023-12-05-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img The first two images result in a white screen on an Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1 (as indicated in the boot log), as shown in the attached video. The img dated 2023-12-05 does not result in a white screen. Seems rather straightforward to understand the question?

If those images were actually identical, Milliways, there would be absolutely no purpose in releasing them.   Very likely if you did a full update on the oldest one it would pretty much match the new one, but they still very likely start with different kernels, which is quite possibly the cause of the problem here -- except for the fact that we have not heard similar complaints, which means either not many people using the 7" screen have installed that image or there is something more peculiar going on.  @Noah: It's implied here there are multiple units with this problem, is that correct?

Thank you! Yess, this is correct. There are at least 2 setups with this Problem. One is a fresh installation and the other one with my project files / installations.

Here also a new observation, the touchscreen responds still with the whitescreen. At least this informations tell me that:
pi@tessie:~ $ evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
...
/dev/input/event3: 10-0038generic ft5x06 (00)
